# Android: AIDL parameter receiving null

Tags: android, aidl

I got an activity and a service that are binded.

When the onServiceConnected is called in the ServiceConnection, I do the next thing:

```
mInterfaceObject = IInterface1.Stub.asInterface(arg1);

mInterfaceObject.register(mController);
```

Where mController is:

```
private final IInterface2.Stub mController = new IInterface2.Stub() {
```

Both IInterface1 and IInterface2 are AIDL files.

Now the problem.
In the implementation of the register in the service. The parameter will be null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eclipse automatically added the next method

```
    @Override
    public IBinder asBinder() {
        return null;
    };
```

This messed up the whole communication. This method shouldn't be overridden.

Comment: Same does Android Studio, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my service implementation. I have 2 aidl files IService & IDataServiceCallback.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) 
    {
        serv = iService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)service);

        try 
         {
               serv.registerCallback(mCallback); 
         } 
         catch (RemoteException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) 
    {
        try 
        {
             serv.unregisterCallback(mCallback);
        } 
        catch(RemoteException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        serv = null;
    }
};
```

Here is my mCallback part.

```
private iDataServiceCallback mCallback = new iDataServiceCallback.Stub() 
{

    @Override
    public void updateResponse(String text) throws RemoteException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    @Override
    public void loginResponse(String text) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message msg = Message.obtain();

        msg.obj = text;

        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }


};
```

on Service side i have implemented this.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}



private final iService.Stub mBinder = new iService.Stub()
{

    @Override
    public void registerCallback(iDataServiceCallback cb) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (cb != null)
        {
            mCallbacks.register(cb);        
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterCallback(iDataServiceCallback cb) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (cb != null) mCallbacks.unregister(cb);  

    }
```

Here is IService.aidl

```
package com.nishant.phototest;

import com.nishant.phototest.iDataServiceCallback;

interface iService
{
    void doLogin(String ip,String port);

    void updatePhoto(in byte[] data);

    void registerCallback(iDataServiceCallback cb); 

    void unregisterCallback(iDataServiceCallback cb);
}
```

Here is IDataServiceCallBack.aidl

```
package com.nishant.phototest;

oneway interface iDataServiceCallback
{
    void loginResponse(String text);

    void updateResponse(String text);
}
```

Hope this will Help you.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I got almost the same thing. But cb will be null here. Could you also post your AIDL file?

Comment: No difference. To bad... Strange that I got the same thing but it receives null....

Comment: can you share your aidl files and your service implementation.

Comment: Are you missing Android Menifest Declaration.?

Comment: Oh! I found the problem... In the mController it automatically added an override methode "public IBinder asBinder() {" and it returned null.... I removed it and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The auto generated concrete class `ICallback.Default` also implements asBinder and returns null.

```
@Override
public IBinder asBinder() {
    return null;
};
```

Make sure to extend `ICallback.Stub` and not `ICallback.Default`.